# Express function as a difference of two non-negative functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a function $f : X \to\mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is any set, one way to write $f$ as a difference of two non negative functions is defining $f_1, f_2 : X \to \mathbb{R}$ as

\begin{align*}
f_1 (x) := \max(f(x),0), \quad f_2(x) := \max(-f(x),0)
\end{align*}

and expressing $f(x) = f_1(x) - f_2(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

Is there any other way to do the same? And does the answer change if we let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, and assume $f$ to be measurable with respect to the measure space?

Answer (score 1):

At least $f_1+g,f_2+g$ where $g$ is a non negative map will also work.